# Как получить id всех соответствующих профилей

Tags: sql

Есть таблица данных о пользователях[image: sql_table]

Нужно написать запрос, чтоб получить user_id, поля с которым содержат все указанные значения, типа так:

```
SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE meta_value = 'олег' AND meta_value = 'odarchenko' and WHERE user_id вышеперечисленных = РАВЕН;
```

Я понял, что вообще не знаю sql, очень нуждаюсь в помощи, ребята.
Такое вообще возможно?

Answer (score 0):

В своем запросе вы указываете условие, чтобы колонка `meta_value` была равна одновременно двум значениям: `'олег'` и `'odarchenko'`. Колонка в одной записи таблицы может иметь только одно значение. Можно поменять условие, чтобы поиск по колонке `meta_value` производился по двум значениям. Для этого нужно использовать оператор `or`. Например:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table
WHERE (meta_value = 'олег' OR meta_value = 'odarchenko')
  AND user_id = 1;
```

В то же время, в данном запросе вы добавляете условие равенства `user_id = РАВЕН`. Получается, вы ищите пользователей с определенными значениями `meta_value` и `user_id`. Это выглядит будто вы ищите определенного пользователя, но чтобы у него было конкретное имя.

> дай мне пользователя с id = 2, но при этом, чтобы у него `meta_value`
>   был равен 'олег'

Возможно не стоит добавлять условие на равенство `user_id = РАВЕН`, чтобы получить именно список попадающих под выборку пользователей.